# Delphi 2007 IXMLHTTPRequest Time out issue

Tags: delphi, msxml6

I'm using Delphi 2007 and have imported MSXML6_TLB.
I'm using IXMLHTTPRequest object to send request to server.

Example:

```
XMLHttp := CoXMLHTTP60.Create;
try
  XMLHttp.open('POST', URL, False, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
  XMLHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
  XMLHttp.send(reqXMLDoc.XML.Text); //--> timeout in 10 secs
  if (XMLHttp.readyState = 4) then
    StrStream.WriteString(UTF8Encode(XMLHttp.responseText));
```

XMLHttp.send() keeps timing out if response takes more than 10 secs. 
I've tested this in other systems and it works fine. But this issue occurs ONLY in my laptop Windows 7, IE 9. Any solutions is welcome. 
P.S. - Is there some registry settings that can override this behaviour.

Comment: try adding `Keep-Alive` header