# IXMLHttpRequest.responseXml is empty, with no parse error, when responseText contains valid Xml

Tags: xml, delphi, xmlhttprequest, delphi-5, serverxmlhttp

i am fetching some XML from [a government web-site](http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/assets/rates_rss/noon/en_all.xml):

```
http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/assets/rates_rss/noon/en_all.xml
```

i am using the following, fairly simple code:

```
var
   szUrl: string;
   http: IXMLHTTPRequest;
begin
   szUrl := 'http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/assets/rates_rss/noon/en_all.xml';

   http := CoXMLHTTP60.Create;
   http.open('GET', szUrl, False, '', '');
   http.send(EmptyParam);

   Assert(http.Status = 200);

   Memo1.Lines.Add('HTTP/1.1 '+IntToStr(http.status)+' '+http.statusText);
   Memo1.Lines.Add(http.getAllResponseHeaders);
   Memo1.Lines.Add(http.responseText);
```

i won't show all the body that returns, but it does return valid xml in the `responseText`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=5
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: Transfer-Encoding
Date: Fri, 30 Mar 2012 14:50:50 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Fri, 30 Mar 2012 14:50:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) PHP/5.3.3 mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/1.0.0d mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.12.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
    xmlns:cb="http://www.cbwiki.net/wiki/index.php/Specification_1.1"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3c.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3c.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#rdf.xsd">
    <channel rdf:about="http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/assets/rates_rss/noon/en_ALL.xml">
        <title xml:lang="en">Bank of Canada: Noon Foreign Exchange Rates</title>
        <link>http://www.bankofcanada.ca/rates/exchange/noon-rates-5-day/</link>
```

Okay, fine, there's valid xml in there. i know it's valid because...well just look at it. But i also know it's valid by parsing it:

```
var
   ...
   szXml: WideString;
   doc: DOMDocument60;
begin
   ...
   szXml := http.responseText;
  
   doc.loadXML(szXml);
   Assert(doc.parseError.errorCode = 0);

   Memo1.Lines.Add('============parsed xml');
   Memo1.Lines.Add(doc.xml);
```

The origianal [`IXmlHttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms760305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contains a [`responseXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property. From MSDN:

> Represents the parsed response entity body.
>
> If the response entity body is not valid XML, this property returns DOMDocument that was parsed so that you can access the error. This property does not return IXMLDOMParseError itself, but it is accessible from DOMDocument.

In my case the responseXml property exists, as it should:

```
Assert(http.responseXml <> nil);
```

And there is no parse error of responseText:

```
doc := http.responseXml as DOMDocument60;
Assert(doc.parseError.errorCode = 0);
```

as there should be, since the xml is valid.

Except that when i look at the `http.responseXml` document object, it's empty:

```
   Memo1.Lines.Add('============responseXml');
   Memo1.Lines.Add(doc.xml);
```

Is is IXMLHttpRequest (and IXMLServerHttpRequest) returning an empty XML document, when:

- there is xml
- the xml is valid
- there is no parse error

In long form:

```
uses
    msxml2_tlb;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    szUrl: string;
    http: IXMLHTTPRequest;
    doc: DOMDocument60;
begin
    szUrl := 'http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/assets/rates_rss/noon/en_all.xml';

    http := CoXMLHTTP60.Create; //or CoServerXmlHttpRequest.Create
    http.open('GET', szUrl, False, '', '');
    http.send(EmptyParam);

    Assert(http.Status = 200);

    doc := http.responseXml as DOMDocument60;
    Assert(doc.parseError.errorCode = 0);

    ShowMessage('"'+doc.xml+'"');
end;
```

How do i make [`XmlHttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms760305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and more importantly [`ServerXMLHTTP60`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762278%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) behave as documented?

Comment: Delphi version information is key in all questions involving the RTL and standard libraries. What version?

Comment: i'm not using any components from Delphi, but Delphi 5.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925798/delphi-2007-ixmlhttprequest-time-out-issue   - note the Keepalive comment. Tried that? Also, what IE version and MS XML version, since those matter in these cases, too. I believe MS XML's HTTP methods use WinInet, which has some fun bugs, and it gets updated when you update IE.

Comment: @WarrenP i tried the timeout; it doesn't change the result (nor should it, since i'm getting a valid response). ie9, msxml 6.0. Do you get the same behavior if you copy-paste the final simplified 8-line version?

Comment: It's something to do with your use of DOMDocument60 instead of `http.responseText`, I think.

Comment: @WarrenP i think you missed something; i *want* to use the `document` (rather than `responseText`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### <strike>I</strike>i found the problem

i used [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to save the http response to a text file. After that i could modify the response file, and instruct fiddler to serve my hand-crafted alternatives, rather than going to the original web-site.

[image]

After 3 hours of fiddling, i managed to track down the problem in the original http response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=5
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: Transfer-Encoding
Date: Fri, 30 Mar 2012 14:50:50 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Fri, 30 Mar 2012 14:50:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) PHP/5.3.3 mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/1.0.0d mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.12.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
```

*should* be:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=5
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: Transfer-Encoding
Date: Fri, 30 Mar 2012 14:50:50 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Fri, 30 Mar 2012 14:50:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) PHP/5.3.3 mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/1.0.0d mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.12.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
```

Once i found the problem, i was able to back-find [the documentation that explain the behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The supported MIME types for MSXML 6.0 are:
>
> - "**text/xml**"
> - "**application/xml**"
> - or anything that ends with "**+xml**", for example "**application/rss+xml**"

The RSS feed i'm fetching is actually a [Resource Definition Format (RDF) feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework), where the content type is supposed to be:

```
application/rdf+xml
```

Their use of:

```
text/html
```

is wrong on so many levels.

So the behavior i'm experiencing is by design; although frustrating - as there's no easy way to know if the `responseXml` is "valid".

- the `responseXml` object will be assigned
- the `parseError` object will be assigned
- the `parseError.ErrorCode` is zero
- the responseXml.documentElement will be nil

Comment: My guess would be that since `text/html` is not supported, the underlying XML parser is not even parsing any data, which would leave the `errorCode` set to zero but not create an `documentElement` object.  If the `responseText` is not empty but the `documentElement` is, you know something went wrong, and you can test for that.

Comment: Many of the Noon feeds on that site are sending the `Content-Type` as `text/html`, but some of them, like "en_USD.xml" and "en_MXN.xml", send `application/xml` instead.

Comment: So what to do? Hack their XML via some string hackage?

Comment: @WarrenP i'm falling back to `if http.responseXml.documentElement = nil then result := GetXmlObjectFromXmlString(http.responseText) else result := http.responseXml;` It's not a thoroughly generic solution, as sometimes there can be an xml document with *no* documentElement. But in this case it's good enough, because if the xml really is empty then they've done something stupid.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with `YouTube` services.

The `responseXml` object is dependent on the content-type/MIME of the response.
You could examine the response `Content-Type` e.g: if `http.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')` contains `text/xml` or `application/xml` *only then* you can refer to `http.responseXml`, otherwise it will be empty (see MSDN [Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757055%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Also note that the `responseXml` parser validation features are always turned off, for security reasons.

**But**, the `http.responseText` will *always* have the `xml` text, no matter what content type is in the response, so you can *always* use a new instance of `DOMDocument` to load the `xml` e.g:

```
...
http := CoXMLHTTP60.Create; // or CoServerXmlHttpRequest.Create 
http.open('GET', szUrl, False, '', '');
http.send(EmptyParam);
Assert(http.Status = 200);

doc := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0') as DOMDocument60; 
doc.async := False;
doc.loadXML(http.responseText); // <- load XmlHttpRequest.responseText into DOMDocument60 and use it
Assert(doc.parseError.errorCode = 0);

// do useful things with doc object...
```

Comment: i don't use the DOMDocument object (and strictly speaking i don't use the XmlHttpRequest object) because the enterprise of mutton-heads thinks it's a good idea to block people's access to the internet (i.e. i have to configure a proxy - which can only be done using IServerXmlHttpRequest). Also, you can't just check for `text/xml`, need to also check for `application/xml`, or `anything/anything+xml` (frought with edge cases i don't even want to care about).

Comment: Read my answer *carefully*. I'm saying that you will have a valid `responseXml.documentElement` object *only* if the response is explicitly set to `text/xml`. I'm saying DON'T rely on `responseXml` and always use `responseText` and `DOMDocument` like in the first code example. `IServerXmlHttpRequest` behaves the same `XmlHttpRequest` when the response content-type is not `text/xml`.

Comment: i'd *prefer* to let the XmlHttpRequest handle the parsing of the response xml text; otherwise the xml has to go through another encode cycle (encoding as UTF-16 BSTR, then parsed again). It's possible that the documentElement is nil even when the content type is `text/xml` - so that's a gotcha.

Comment: I'd also prefer that. But this is by design. :/

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works in Delphi XE and Delphi 7:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    szUrl: string;
    http: IXMLHTTPRequest;
    doc: {$ifndef UNICODE}WideString{$else}string{$endif};
begin
    szUrl := 'http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/assets/rates_rss/noon/en_all.xml';

    http := CoXMLHTTP60.Create; //or CoServerXmlHttpRequest.Create
    http.open('GET', szUrl, False, '', '');
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
    http.send(EmptyParam);

    Assert(http.Status = 200);

    doc := UTF8Encode(http.responseText);

    Memo1.Lines.text := doc;
//  ShowMessage('"'+doc.xml+'"');
end;
```

Hope it works for you in Delphi 5, too. Of course, any unicode characters are going to turn into ? on you, in non-unicode delphi versions.

Comment: `respoonseText` works, it's `responseXml` that is empty (though there's no parse error)

Answer (score 0):

You are retreiving the `xml` from the `DOMDocument` object itself, but you should be grabbing it from the first node in the document's tree instead, eg:

```
doc := http.responseXml as DOMDocument60; 
Assert(doc.parseError.errorCode = 0); 
ShowMessage('"' + doc.DocumentElement.childNodes.Item(0).xml + '"');
```

Microsoft's own examples in the documentation for `DOMDocument` and the `xml` property show exactly that kind of logic.

Comment: In this case the `documentElement` is nil.

Comment: Well, then that explains why the `xml` is empty - there is nothing in the `DOMDocument`.

Comment: At the very least it is deceiving: there is nothing in the DOMDocument yet it's valid XML.