# MSXML: XMLHTTP doesn't support charset from header

Tags: delphi, msxml

I'm using `MSXML2_TLB.pas` generated from the `Microsoft XML` type library to call a pretty simple web-service, so I don't need the full XML wrapping and just do this:

```
var
  r:XMLHTTP;
begin
  r:=CoXMLHTTP.Create;
  r.open('POST',WebServiceURL,false,'','');
  r.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/xml');
  r.send('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" '+
    'xmlns:ns="http://somebigcorporation.com/api/ws1/">'+
    '<soapenv:Body>'+
    //snip: irrelevant to the question
    '</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>');

  if r.status<>200 then raise Exception.Create(r.statusText);
  Result:=(r.responseXML as DOMDocument).documentElement.firstChild.firstChild.selectSingleNode('importantData');
end;
```

The webservice responds nicely with status 200 and `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1`.

In some cases, `documentElement` is nil (and the above code throws an access violation). Apparently `responseXML` exists, but only to offer a `parseError` object (it says so in [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), and `parseError.reason` in these cases is `An invalid character was found in text content.`.

Why is the parser not taking the 'charset' value from the response header? Is there a way to tell the XMLHTTP instance to use the charset value from the response header?

*Update:* I don't know if it's important, but the response also doesn't start with `<?xml` and even if it did I have no way to request/modify it so it would have an `encoding="iso-8859-1"` attribute.

Comment: You say that *the response also doesn't start with <?xml*, so is that even valid XML ? Or you mean that the prolog does not contain encoding ? If the latter, I'm afraid you're out of luck, *For reliable processing, XML documents that use character encodings other than UTF-8 or UTF-16 must include an encoding declaration in the XML declaration.* ([`Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757065(v=vs.85).aspx))

Comment: Post it as an answer so I can accept it, please.

Comment: @StijnSanders, you could use `r.responseText` (modify it as you wish to include the char-set declaration) and load it into a new XMLDOC instead of using `responseXML` object directly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9959386/937125 might be helpful.

Comment: @kobik: yes that's what I've used to make it work (for now)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the charset in the request so the result is correct.

```
r.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

Comment: The result _is_ correct. The request is also handled correctly, I leave the request body encoding to the XMLHTTP object. I doubt setting the request content type will affect the response content type. It's the fact XMLHTTP apparently misinterpret's the response's encoding that is the problem.

Comment: @StijnSanders, This is not the core of your problem, but in any case you *should* specify  your request `Content-Type`. the web-service *might* be expecting (and handling) this. for example, if you specify a request with content-type of UTF8, your might be surprised to find out that the server response with UTF8 as well. this is true for ASMX .net web-services for examples.